# absolute responsive image background

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, responsive

I have a little question due to position of background image in my footer.

As You can see on the picture, my current background image (green dotted line with ball - it is svg image) is placed in the middle if the footer.

[image]

I would like to place it in the position of the red line, staying there while resizing window.
Code of it is:

```css
footer{
  position: relative;
  
  /* START OF IMAGE BG */
  &:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("/wp-content/themes/company/static/img/line.svg");
    -moz-background-size:90%;
    background-size:90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  /* END OF IMG BG */  
  
  padding: rem-calc(45 20);
  @media #{$medium-up}{
    padding: rem-calc(85);
  }
  background-color: $bluedark;
  color: $white;
  min-height: rem-calc(500);
  p{
    font-size: rem-calc(12);
    @media #{$medium-up}{
      font-size: rem-calc(16);
    }
    font-weight: 300;
    &.section-header{
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    &.bold{
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    &.green{
      color: $green;
    }
  }
  .social-media{
    img{
      display: inline-block;
      margin: rem-calc(0 5 20 5);
      max-height: rem-calc(20);
      @media #{$medium-up}{
        max-height: rem-calc(40);
      }
    }
  }
  .underline{
    margin-top: rem-calc(50);
    border-top: 1px solid $bluegrey;
    padding-top: rem-calc(20);
    .logo{
      float: left;

      width: rem-calc(200);
      height: rem-calc(45);
      background: url("/wp-content/themes/company/static/img/logo_light.svg");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    select{
      float: right;
    }
  }
}
```

And html is:

```
<footer>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="flex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <p class="section-header">O nas</p>
            <p>O Firmie</p>
            <p>Zespół</p>
            <p class="green">Blog</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <p class="section-header">Pomoc</p>
            <p>FAQ</p>
            <p>Regulamin</p>
            <p>Polityka prywatności</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <p class="section-header">Social Media</p>
            <div class="social-media">
                <img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/social-media/facebook.png">
                <img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/social-media/twitter.png">
                <img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/social-media/instagram.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <p class="section-header">Kontrakt</p>
            <div class="button green">Formularz kontaktowy</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row underline">
        <div class="logo"></div><span>
        <select>
          <option value="Polski">Polski</option>
          <option value="English">English</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know it is wrong placed due to top:0 however I dont know how to make it stay right on the top border of footer.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Please include full markup (HTML and CSS) so that the problem can be reproduced in the question itself. Posting just the CSS leaves your question open to interpretation and is of less use to others that may experience a similar issue.

Comment: If the line is just in the middle of the image you can set `top:-50%`, otherwise try changing the value to find the correct

Comment: @blonfu top : X% does not work because when window is reszied image goes up

Comment: @Hidden Hobbes full  markup added.

Comment: you are right, is a background image. Add also `background-position: center;`

Comment: @blonfu actually i cannot add 'background-position: center;' because it will center the line which i want o start exactly from the left :) Howewer i still don't know how to solve my problem with image position

Comment: I write an answer, I think you can do something similar

Comment: @blonfu oh sorry, I haven't seen it. I'll try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar example of yours, I think its usefull for your purpouse:

```css
  div {
    border: solid 1px green;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  footer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: -50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("http://www.curtainshopsouthport.co.uk/scissors.png");
    -moz-background-size: 90%;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 50%;
  }
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quis placeat architecto dolore recusandae nam amet, voluptate consequatur tenetur, quibusdam cupiditate culpa perferendis praesentium ab quasi voluptatum doloremque illum suscipit ea. Placeat
  aperiam tempore maiores minus harum sint debitis beatae sit, eos voluptas est temporibus animi ullam praesentium voluptates molestiae dolore illo officiis blanditiis dolores. Qui labore asperiores quia dolore amet, culpa consectetur est quibusdam iusto
  incidunt maxime aliquid sit eius explicabo aut, possimus corporis temporibus. Alias officia libero repellat veritatis, obcaecati repudiandae at voluptas, maxime doloremque facilis, sunt praesentium voluptatibus eaque provident natus, earum asperiores?
  Possimus voluptatem, soluta deserunt.</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: adding background-position: left 50%; solve the problem. Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have `overflow` issues, all you should need to do is replace `top:0` with `bottom:100%`

```
footer{
  position: relative;
  &:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 100%; /* change here */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    background: url("img/line.svg");
    -moz-background-size:90%;
    background-size:90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately when i change top:0 to bottom: 100%, the image goes totally out of footer